# Java multithread code does not fully consumes the cores on some procs

Tags: java, multithreading, multicore

I have some intensive processing code that reads chunks from a file, process the data and writes to output file IN THE SAME ORDER. Some numbers: input file is about 29MB, output file is about 39MB, there are 39461 chunks.
Single thread version takes 100% processor (for multicore only one core is used).

Again some numbers (seconds for each proc):

Pentium 4 (1 core) 2.8GHz   4302.407

Intel Xeon (1 core) 2.8GHz  3805.281

Intel E8300 (2 cores) 1773.062

Intel Q6600 (4 cores) 2202.231

Intel i5-4440 (4 cores) 1300.127

i7-3632QM (4 cores, 8 threads)  1412.191

Interesting to see that better rated i7 is almost as fast as the old E8300 in single thread and slower than i5-4440.

To take advantage of multicore structure I modified the code. I launch a number of threads equal to the number of cores(threads) - Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors(). Each thread reads from the file and picks a number (synchronized block), does the intense processing, then waits in line for its picked number to be available in order to write in the output file, does the writing and increment the number that shows whose turn is now to write in output file (also synchronized).
The code works fine, the output file is generated correctly.

For the above processors(multicore) I got this :

Intel E8300 (2 cores)   937.766

Intel Q6600 (4 cores)   657.515

Intel i5-4440 (4 cores) 345.244

i7-3632QM (4 cores, 8 threads)  584.346

Improvement indeed compared to singlethread version, but: Task Manager (all systems on Windows) shows to my satisfaction 100% busy on all procs/all cores except for i7 - here it uses all the 8 threads but only about 40% each, and the results reflect this behaviour. i7 falls between old q6600 and new (but less rated) i5-4440 and closer to the first one.

Some remarks:

The way threads wait to write in the output file is:

```
        while(ai.intValue() != outSeed.intValue()) {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        }
```

ai is the number picked when it read from input file, and now waits its turn to write. outSeed is incremented by the threads that succeded to write.

Tested intensely on Q6600 the 10ms sleep proved to give the best times. i5 also improved very well. i7 not so good, so I tried sleep(3), sleep(1), sleep(0). For 3ms i7 ran in 529.782 time. Sleep(0) raised the busy percentage to approx. 60% for all 8 threads and time was 440.897. It is better but it is not enough as I would expect less than 200 seconds, and I think it is possible if I can achieve a more busy processor.

Again, the resulted file is what expected, the behavior is what expected on most procs (100% busy) except for i7-3632QM. What are your suggestions? I tried setPriority=realTime from TaskManager, no effect. Is it possible that the Op. System limits the proc use? 
Latter I may have access to a six core Xeon and try on that too.
Thanks for reading.

Comment: Having sleeps in your code and trying to manually optimize this kind of code is a big smell to me. Maybe you should not worry about small things like these? Do you have reason to?

Comment: Can your "issue" be related to HyperThreading? Meaning, Windows TaskManager will show you 8 cores where in reality only 4 phisical cores exists (which can process two different pipelines thanks to HT) but they are not real real cores after all?

Comment: @Claudio Yes I tried only 4 threads but it's the same : busy max. at about 40%, i stopped it, the time would have been lower. I need it to use 100% like the other processors. It's very curious why it behaves like this on i7, and different on the others.

Comment: Does your worker thread notify the controlling code when it is done processing and waiting to write? Because obviously, at that point you should proceed with creating a new thread to do more work. Also, do you pre-load the chunks into a buffer so there's no latency when a thread wants to grab a chunk?

Answer (score 5):

1. Hyperthreading will obviously not linearly scale performance. Your i7 has 4 cores, not 8, and only has a bit of logic in front of those cores which make context switching faster. You can only expect up to 20-30% increase over the performance of a 4-core system without hyperthreading.
2. What you see in the Task Manager does not directly reflect the efficiency of individual Java threads because threads get reassigned between cores. The same readout may be accomplished with less than 8 threads, each running at full speed.
3. The mere fact that you have 8 threads instead of 4 may cause some blockage issues as you are unable to feed all 8 threads with work. That explicit `sleep` may influence this.
4. You should try replacing your polling loop with a design that relies on `Phaser`. That class seems to be a perfect match for your use case.
5. What you are coding has already been provided in Java 8 with the Streams API. I have recently written a [post](http://www.airpair.com/v1/posts/parallel-processing-of-io-based-data-with-java-streams) about exactly this subject, which explains how to use the Streams API to parallelize any I/O-based source. You may try that avenue as well.

Comment: I already tried to force only 4 threads instead of 8 on i7 but seeing that busy is again limited to 40% (on 4 threads from 8) I stopped it. My big question is why i7 refuses to go 100%, even in single thread. I'm trying to get the best of the CPU. It's a time critical process, every second counts.

Comment: Are you saying that, with single-threaded code, you see 40% utilization of a single "thread" in Task Manager, and all others at 0%?

Comment: If you want to go raw and low level you might want to try assigning core affinity to each one of your threads to a different physical cores. There are ways to do that.

Comment: Your measurements do not support this because, with single-threaded, you get just 10% worse with i7 than with i5. I've checked the CPU specs, your i7 has 2.2 GHz and i5 has 3.1 GHz. Also, obviously, you are not comparing CPUs with everything else being equal; you are comparing complete machines with those CPUs.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik How do you conclude hyperthreading isn't worth it in his case? HT can increase performance by a large margin *if* the two threads perform mainly computation (raytraycing is usually cited as prime example). The TC hasn't really provided info on what his threads *do*, so your first paragraph seems a bit of a premature conclusion.

Comment: Anyways, since he is running such exhaustive performance tests it would be a nice test to run the same process on the same machine but with HT turned off and compare results.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik well, the numbers are from real tests. i5 is on W7 professional, i7 on w7 home. I don't see a problem with these numbers. I'm annoyed of the i7 behavior. Maybe OS limits the java process resources. Is it possible to load Knoppix for example and run it there? The tests are run from USB stick if that is important.  I will check later Streams API, thanks for suggestion.

Comment: The test numbers are what counts, and CPU utilization reported by Windows does not, that was my point. It is not at all obvious what that 40% utilization indicates, and the test numbers say the utilization must have been much higher.

Comment: @Claudio you mean to disable HT from BIOS and try again?

Comment: @Durandal I have adapted my first sentence to be more aligned with your comments.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik in this case the small busy % is in accordance with the results. 40% busy = less than expected results (584s instead 200s)

Comment: I was commenting your claim that a single-threaded application shows 40% utilization, whereas your numbers say that i7 took 1400 vs. i5's 1300 seconds. If anything, that result indicates that i7, with its 2.2 GHZ, ran *over the limit* to get so close to the 3.1 GHz i5.

Answer (score 2):

You are reading and writing files.

There will be times when your application will be blocked on I/O and therefore will not be consuming CPU.

Comment: This may or may not be relevant, depending on actual design. In addition, it doesn't explain why the 8-thread case is impacted by this much more severely than any other case.

Answer (score 2):

After the comments of Marko and Claudio I went back to testing:

-@Claudio I disabled HT in i7 and ran again multicore : busy 70%/core and results slightly better (sleep(0)): 431.099

-@Marko : I ran again single thread on i7 with HT enabled and observed that the java process was 13% from total but there were 2 threads from 8 busy instead of one at about 40%. This is OS intervention, seems that somehow divides the job on tho threads. Your observations were right, I didn't notice there was a second thread busy on i7.

-ran again on E8300, single thread is 50 busy from total but both cores are loaded about 50%. Again OS decision. Multithread load is 90%.

-single thread on Q6600 java process has 25% cpu but on graphic view all the cores have some loading (there are no other intense processes), so OS divides the single thread to all cores somehow. Multithread is 90%.

@Steve C - the faster per thread i5 should have the same problem. The i/o operations on i7 system should not be slower than on i5 system as it is fairly new

The impression that all procs use 100% except i7 which uses 40% is now diminishing, but still would like to get more from i7. Perhaps using what Marko suggested will help. Right now I'm somehow satisfied with the results but if smaller times are required I will change the code to see the difference.

Comment: New test on xeon e5-2620 6 cores, 12 threads. 90% busy on all threads, system is w7 professional . Result 330.034, just slightly better than i5. It means that a lot of busy time is sleep, waiting to read/write. At this point should change the code. Still not clear why i7 refused to get 90% busy. The main reason I see now is OS: w7 home on i7 vs. w7 pro on others.